# Automation of a process on daily basis by transferring File(whose name with DATE stamp) from server

Tags: command-line, ftp

"Fetching data from server by FTP command" is not a problem. But to fetch the today's file from the server ,whose name is Like(BACKUP20141210) and if it presents in a folder with previous dated backup files like (BACKUP20141209,BACKUP20141208,...), what kind of FTP script is suitable here? Here, I share my FTP script:

```
open myftp.myserver.com    
myusername    
mypassword    
lcd "c:\myfolder"    
cd webfolder    
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do echo get myfile%%a%%b%%c
```

But I get an "Invalid command" response with the "`for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do echo get myfile%%a%%b%%c`" line.and it stops.

Can anyone suggest any relative answer of it. Actually I need an automatic process of getting file on daily basis from server to client by FTP. My main concern is that the file name is date oriented.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do echo get myfile%%a%%b%%c` is not a valid ftp command ...

Comment: Instead of it is there any other OPTION.Then how can I make the process to be understood about the FILE NAME.Moreover at the remote machine there are many FILEs having name with date stamp,(may be previous day or more previous days)

Comment: Use WinSCP. See [Automate file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server or SFTP server](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation)

Comment: Try writing a script to create an FTP script, customized according to today's date. (P.S. You might get more help here if you (a) edit your question title to better reflect what problem you're having, (b) specify what operating system you're using (looks like Windows), and maybe (c) specify what FTP software you're using.)

Comment: I have Windows XP and use SFTP for file transfer.actually i need a complete automatic process which help to fetch Data on Daily ,say at a particular time. Though at the remote machine there are many FILEs having name with date stamp,(may be previous day or more previous days).